# ClearCase view that ONLY shows files/directories attached to a label (not latest)

Tags: clearcase

I am using a Config spec such as

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element *  MYLABEL
element * /main/LATEST
```

Since the creation of `MYLABEL`, I have added new files and directories. I would prefer not to see the new stuff.  I left off the "`element * /main/LATEST`" and that doesn't help. Any ideas?

It doesn't seem like should have to resort to TIME or DATE qualifiers. Shouldn't the label by itself be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order of the section rules, and **ends with**:

```
element * MYLABEL
```

Starts with the only rule (element * MYLABEL) and check if you see anything.

Then add *before* that rule the selection rule of the parent folder (most likey the vob) which may not have that label:

```
element /vobs/MyVob /main/LATEST
element /vobs/MYVob/ParentFolder /main/LATEST

element * MYLABEL
```

That will only work if mylabel has been applied on *all* elements under a certain path.

Each parent folder above that '`MYLABEL`' must be selected by the `/main/LATEST` rule.
If `MYLABEL` has been applied for all elements under `A/B/C/D`,

- `A` needs to be selected by `/main/LATEST`
- `A/B` needs to be selected by `/main/LATEST`
- `A/B/C` needs to be selected by `/main/LATEST`

Then you end with `element * MYLABEL`.

---

If you only apply `MYLABEL` to a particular subfolder, and would like to be sure to see that label only on that subfolder, you can do:

```
element /MyVob                            /main/LATEST
element /MyVob/projects                   /main/LATEST
element /myVob/projects/subProject1/...   MYLABEL
element *                                 /main/LATEST
```

That way, any other subProjectX folder will be in `/main/LATEST`, except for the content of `subProject1` (because of the `/...` three dots notation).

Comment: Haven't got it to work yet but here is another question which may shed some light. When I create a dynamic view, I see a list of vobs.

Comment: @kevinzamora are you on Windows on Unix? `/vobs/aVob/xxx` assumed Unix. For Windows, it would be `/AVob/xxx`

Comment: I am on windows. Sorry my edit got curtailed. To give you some more info, My structure is similar to the following. It is vob/projects/subproject1 , vob/projects/subproject2.  Now, I only apply a label to subprojectX and all files and directories below it. I don't apply a label to vob and projects folder because the label is subproject sensitive. Does that make sense? Therefore, I understand your instructions would be for a given subproject would be element vob /main/latest, element vob/projects /main/latest, element vob/projects/subproject? /main/latest, element * MYLABEL

Comment: @kevinzamora It does make sense. See my edited answer.

Comment: Woo hoo! Works! Awesome. I've been wondering how to do that for such a  long time. Thank you. It is too bad you have to repeat that for every directory but I'll take your solution anyday.  :-)