# ClearCase Config Spec: load only files with specific label from certain directory

Tags: label, clearcase, config-spec

Suppose I have a VOB foo/. In this VOB lies a directory bar/ which contains labeled and non-labeled files. But bar/ is not the only directory in foo/, but all others don't have labeled files.
Is there a way to write a config spec with the following behaviour:

- load all elements that are checked out
- for every directory *except* foo/bar/ load the main/LATEST version
- for the directory foo/bar/ load *only* the files which have that specific label, if this label does not exist, *do not* load the main/LATEST version

The normal config spec would be

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * LABEL
element * /main/LATEST
load /foo
```

But obviously it would then load also the non-labeled versions in /foo/bar. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add paths to your config spec in order to apply specific selection rule to said paths:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element foo/bar/... MYLABEL
element foo/bar/... -none
element * /main/LATEST
load /foo
```

I would recommend testing that config spec in a dynamic view first, then apply it to the snapshot view.

The three dots notation (`foo/bar/...`) means: the `bar` folder and all its subelements.

Note that this won't always display *all* elements labelled with `MYLABEL`: if one the parent folders has *not* the label `MYLABEL`, no other sub-element will be visible, accessible and selected.
This is especially true here considering the rule `element foo/bar/... -none` which is there to prevent selecting `/main/LATEST` for `foo/bar` (is there is no `MYLABEL`)

The order of the rules is important here, since the first one which applies is the one used by ClearCase: you can find a similar idea in "[ClearCase view that ONLY shows files/directories attached to a label (not latest)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23228792/6309)"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I won't get to try it out until Thursday, but I will accept the answer as soon as I have done so.

Comment: I tried the solution above: I had an existing snapshot with some directories to exclude, but the `-none` did not work. When looking at the `VOB` the folders still exist with all of their content. Note that the folders I want to remove are links to other folders in a different `VOB`. I want to remove them because the snapshot `VIEW` does not know how to handle  symbolic link (It duplicates the files - this after we get compilation/debug issues, because checking out in one `VOB` is not reflected in the other `VOB`).

Comment: @Juv Not sure, I always used that config spec successfully before. What version of ClearCase are you using, on which OS? (both client and server)

Comment: ClearCase version 9.0.1.9 (both client and server) on Windows 10. I thought it might be connected to the fact that this is an existing snapshot. Or to the fact that this folders are Symbolic links, and I want to show them only in their original VOB. We considered removing the links, but due years of mix ups, there are too many projects to fix references in.

Comment: @Juv Would https://stackoverflow.com/a/24952026/6309 help?

Comment: Actually I don't like the answer there,  because it tells me that I need to un-reference the original directory, which means I will  loose both directories which I want to avoid. BTW the server is Windows Server 2016.