# Clearcase create new element in specific branch

Tags: version-control, clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-remote-client

My team has a VOB in clearcase. Suppose my project looks something like this :

```
Project (Directory)
- Module 1 (Sub-directory)
- Module 2 (Sub-directory)
```

When I write my config-specs, I want to specify that if a new file is created in Module 1 sub-directory, it goes to Branch **branch/LATEST**, otherwise, if it is created somewhere else, I would like it to be versioned on **main/LATEST**.

I am able to specify that any newly created file goes to branch B using the spec:

```
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch branch
```

Is there any way to specify the branching based on where that file is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`config_spec`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm), you can use a path pattern like:

```
element /my_vob/module1/... .../branch/LATEST
element /my_vob/module1/... /main/LATEST -mkbranch branch
element /my_vob/module1/... /main/0 -mkbranch branch
```

That supposes `module1` is a folder within a vob.
See "[ClearCase Config Spec: load only files with specific label from certain directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28805606/6309)" as another example.

- The '`/...`' means folder and its content (as opposed to '`*`' with means only the content, not the folder itself)
- The '`.../branch`' means `branch` accessed from any other branch (`/main/branch`, `/main/anotherbranch/branch`, ...)

Note that if module1 or module2 were UCM components, they could be managed in their own stream and would have their own branch.
You project could then have symbolic link to two different UCM views.

Comment: You probably want to amend the answer to use "..." after /myvob/module1 instead of "*". The former means "this directory and everything underneath it, including subdirectories." The latter means "Everything in this subdirectory NOT including items in subdirectories."

Comment: @BrianCowan Thank you. I have amended the answer. I used dots by the past (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28805606/6309)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That perfectly helps. Could you please elaborate what this path pattern achieves.

Comment: @ManishSharma the path patterns allows to apply a config spec only to the files which match that pattern.